# DirectX error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dx9.h'

Tags: c++, c

I have installed the latest `directx` and I keep receiving this error:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dx9.h'
```

Comment: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dx9.h' this error

Comment: Well, having the latest version isn't going to help.  It is not a standard DX header, you'll have to dig up a really old version of the DirectX SDK, back from before the days that it was integrated into the Windows SDK.  Probably from around the time that DX9 got released, 13 years ago.

Comment: @HansPassant I believe [this ancient relic](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812) will do it.